# mod_rewrite make directory request instead request page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to make a request to a directory, like

```
www.mysite.com/directory/itemname/
```

redirect to

```
www.mysite.com/directory/itemname/index.cfm
```

How would I do so?

Answer (score 1):

You probably just want to use DirectoryIndex to .htaccess or httpd.conf specify the default index page

```
DirectoryIndex index.cfm
```